# Compare column A in 2 sheets if a match fill column B-E with data from master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs and compares column 'A' in a 'daily' sheet and a 'master' sheet (but only up to the first hyphon) .
 Then it cut&pastes any matches to a sheet3, then displays any non matches in a userform.
what i want is any matches that are found, i want the data in column B-E from the 'master sheet' pasted into column B-E on the 'sheet3'. while keeping the columa 'A' match details from the daily sheet.

```
Sub unknownservers()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rngTocut As Range, x As Range
Dim iListCount As Long, iCtr As Long
Dim firstHyp1 As Integer, firstHyp2 As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1") 'master list
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2") ' daily 
Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
  iListCount = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' Loop through the "master" list.
For Each x In ws1.Range("A1:A" & ws1.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For iCtr = 1 To iListCount
        firstHyp1 = InStr(1, x.Value, ".")
        firstHyp2 = InStr(1, ws2.Cells(iCtr, 1).Value, ".")
        firstHyp1 = IIf(firstHyp1 = 0, Len(x.Value), firstHyp1 - 1)
        firstHyp2 = IIf(firstHyp2 = 0, Len(ws2.Cells(iCtr, 1).Value), firstHyp2 - 1)

        If UCase(Left(ws2.Cells(iCtr, 1).Value, firstHyp2)) = UCase(Left(x.Value,      firstHyp1)) Then
            If rngTocut Is Nothing Then
                Set rngTocut = ws2.Cells(iCtr, 1)
            Else
                Set rngTocut = Union(rngTocut, ws2.Cells(iCtr, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next iCtr
Next

If Not rngTocut Is Nothing Then rngTocut.EntireRow.Cut Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A"  & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) = 0 Then Exit Sub

For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If r.Value > "" Then
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & r.Value
    End If
Next r
' create listbox with send email option
frmunknownservers.Textunknownservers.Text = msg
frmunknownservers.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Does that `Cut` actually work?  I thought that doesn't work on multiple selections...  If you build up a `rngToCopy` as you're constructing `rngToCut` then you can also deal with that after the loop.   The range you need to add for each matching row will be `ws2.Cells(iCtr, 1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1,4)`

Comment: yes range to cut works

Answer (score 0):

This is the very situation that `vLookup` was made for.  You can modify the lookup string to match both sheets (up to the first hyphen) and then the formula would fill in whatever column values that you want.  Then you could just loop through one of the columns and put all of the N/A's in a listbox.